# What was the joke behind the quidditch tryouts scene in Puffs?

Tags: harry-potter, puffs-play

In the off-Broadway play "Puffs," about Hufflepuff students and their inconsequential role in the greater Harry Potter story arc, year 6 includes an extremely protracted scene that mystified me. I've read all the HP books repeatedly and seen all the movies, but I cannot figure out where this scene is coming from.

The scene involves Zachary Smith running quidditch team tryouts for House Hufflepuff, and mostly comes down to him doing an AMA (Ask Me Anything. It's like opening the floor to questions) with the other students. It's probably the longest scene in the play, and although it was funny on its own, I can't figure out what it's parodying or how it relates to the actual Harry Potter storyline.

Any insight there?

Comment: without access to the text of the scene, it will be extremely difficult to analyze

Comment: According to its [shows](https://www.broadway.com/shows/puffs-or-seven-years-increasingly-eventful-years-certain-school-magic-and-magic-nws/) page it was filmed and shown in cinemas at one point. So it might be available out there somewhere.

Comment: And the scripts is available [for $10](http://www.puffstheplay.com/script#page-content-section).

Comment: @Jontia It’s on Amazon Prime.

Comment: Could you include the actual joke?

Comment: How can I include the joke when I'm asking what the joke is? The joke is the entire scene...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole scene is ad-lib.

[image: Shot from play explaining scene is ad-lib]

This image is from the version on Amazon, in which the Sports Try-out scene in year six is a condensed rendition of the 2008 rom-com, [27 Dresses](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TwentysevenDresses). There are a couple of alternative versions of the same scene shown during the credits including a joke/bad [Capoeira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capoeira) session, but there isn't an Ask Me Anything (AMA) version in the Amazon video.

So, while I still haven't seen the AMA version, given the nature of the scene it is unlikely to refer to anything specific with the Harry Potter stories it's just the cast having some fun.

[image: Reminder: This is ad-lib]

Comment: I'm confused... what does *27 dressess* have to do with *Puffs*?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Absolutely nothing. But the ad-lib scene in year six at the Sports tryouts is a condensed rendition of the film with Zach as the male lead. In the version on Amazon.

Comment: Ah. That makes more sense now. I misunderstood. Although now, I'm wondering about the Capoeira content... :-P

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I would really like to see the AMA version.

Comment: so...if I understand right, OP saw the play and there was an ad-lib section and OP is asking what some of the jokes in an ad-lib scene were?

Comment: @NKCampbell with the additional point that the OP did not know that the scene was ad-lib.

Comment: Correct. Moreover, the cast was having a really hard time containing themselves during the scene, apparently finding it hysterical beyond their limits. So I was really at a loss. It makes sense that they were having fun with friends on stage.